# Adobe-DTM, splitting datalayer variable in Data Element custom script

Tags: javascript

in DTM I'm trying to get a data element to capture one part of my data layer variable, which looks like value1|value2|value3.

However when trying in the console, i'm getting undefined. Code below

```
function test() {
    var myArray = window.dataLayer.variable_name.split("|")
    return myArray[0];
}
```

I'm pretty new to javascript but I thought this would return the first value in my array (value1). Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: log the result of `window.dataLayer.variable_name.includes("|")`

Comment: @kudeh Hi, it says true.

Comment: try adding a semicolon at the end of the first line in the `test` function